# How can I lower the throttling temperature

Tags: windows-8, cpu, bios, temperature, throttling

I have an Acer V17 Nitro with Windows 8. The temperatures get way too hot on this laptop, even when using very non-demanding applications.

How do I lower the throttling temperature so that it begins throttling CPU down at say 80 deg C instead of 96 deg C?

I don't care if performance is impacted, I don't want to burn a hole in the laptop.

Thanks,

Comment: Normally you would inspect (and most likely replace) the thermal paste. A laptop should not be running that hot unless something inside is wrong. For example clogged up fan with dust etc.

Comment: Also, take a look at the power scheme settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the fan(s) and redo the thermal paste if needed. Keeping the laptop on a hard surface instead of the carpet/bed make a huge difference as well.
2. If you're running Windows, you'll be able to adjust the power settings. These will reduce the CPU and other system throttling to assist in lowering temps.